# Unable to get grub after upgrading to windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have ubuntu along with windows8. Recently I upgraded to windows8.1. After that I am not getting the grub, which i used to get with windows 8. But i can access ubuntu 13.04 by pressing F9 while starting and in boot options, ubuntu, then i get grub and i can access ubuntu. Files are as usual. I tried to run boot repair but its rectifying this problem.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6393514
 It says, The boot files of the OS now in use-ubuntu 13.04 are far from the start of the disk. Your bios may not detect them. I dont have idea whar it is. Can anyone help on the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Guessing from your pastebin log that grub is in `sda6` - meaning that it is in the 6th partition from the start of the disk, which is what causes the error - Windows for some reason seems to have 5 or 6 of the partitions on the hard disk. The bootloader will search for a boot file thing from the beginning of the disk, but the Windows one is in `sda4`, meaning that it will pick that before it has even found grub - updating grub may help, but this is probably Windows doing what it does best - being stupid + evil, so it will be hard to sort out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Restore Grub After Windows 8.1 Upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431011/cannot-restore-grub-after-windows-8-1-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

I got it back when I changed chose back up EFI files option in advanced boot repair option.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the BIOS screen. Check the "Startup Order" tab, there you'll see Windows Boot Loader in position 1.

Change the order so "ubuntu" is in the first position.

I just recovered my partition this way.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Series 9, changing the booting order (promoting "ubuntu" in first position) did not work: the order with the Windows Boot Loader in first position was restored after every reboot.

Here's what worked:

- Boot into the BIOS setup (F2)
- Go to Boot --> Boot device priority
- In the boot priority order, go to "Windows Boot Manager" (which should be in position 1) and disable it (Shift + 1)
- Save BIOS settings and reboot

You should now have your GRUB menu back, from which you can boot Windows or Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score -1):

If you can access ubuntu, reinstall grub:

Note than in my example, I have grub installed in the first hard drive. Your installation may be different (sdb for example):

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

If you're not sure which one to use:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Will show you the devices and partitions you have.

After installing grub, update it:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work. When I ran boot repair, after its successful completion, it says, "The boot files of[The OS now in use-Ubuntu 13.04]are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4,>200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Seperate /boot partition:] option of [Boot repair]."
I don't understand how to do.