# Boot Repair doesn't work after Windows 8.1 Update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

*(The original title of this post was "Boot Repair doesn't work after **April 2014** Windows 8.1 Update" since I wanted to highlight that this is not about the 8.0 -> 8.1 update, but the update for 8.1 that came out in April 2014.)*

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1. Today I got the "big" Windows 8.1 Update and now my PC doesn't show GRUB anymore, but boots straight into Windows. I've tried running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from Ubuntu on a USB stick, but that doesn't seem to do anything. The system still boots directly into Windows every time.

I'm sure I just need to change some setting in Boot Repair, but I don't want to do that without knowing what I'm doing. :)

Here's my Boot Repair Ubuntu Pastebin thingy:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7230979/

Thanks!

**Update:**

Now I effed everything up completely.

Since I didn't get an answer here, I tried fiddeling with the Boot Repair options. Now the following message flashes for a second when I start the PC:

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - 800000000000000E
Failed to load image
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi - 800000000000000E
Failed to load image
```

...just before stopping at this line:

```
Operating System Not Found
```

Here's my updated Boot Repair report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7233853/

Comment: Possibly this is specific to EFI/GPT. I also received it yesterday but it didn't caused any issue (No UEFI).

Comment: Can you check this answer - [Cannot Restore Grub After Windows 8.1 Upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/q/431011)

Comment: @Rudolph, I ran into exactly the same issue. A method to get grub working is documented here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/491425/grub-not-working-after-windows-8-1-update-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/492778#492778