# Can't see GRUB after running boot repair

Tags: grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I've got a machine with Windows 8 and just upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. After this, I couldn't see GRUB while booting.

So, I ran boot repair (have a look at the [boot repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7245690)), but still it didn't work. Secure boot is disabled.

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/431087/27968)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Restore Grub After Windows 8.1 Upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431011/cannot-restore-grub-after-windows-8-1-upgrade)